# just implemented Recyclerview in my code, replacing Listview. everything works fine. But some times its shows blank screen

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)     
    view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getActivity())
                        .color(Color.BLACK)
                        .build());

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        final Mobile_recycle_Adapter mobilerecycleAdapter = new Mobile_recycle_Adapter(mMobiledetailsList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mobilerecycleAdapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url = "http://onam.leah.in/new/item_details.php";
```

My log cat is shown as a error:

> ```
>  15:25:53.476 E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
>
>  15:25:53.655 E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
> ```

Comment: i assume somewhere in your code you are calling ` recyclerView.setAdapter(null);` or for some raeson RecyclerView is being recreated but you are not handling activity/fragment/view recreation properly.

Comment: Let me check my code thoroughly and get back to you.Thanks